# Entity Framework. Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "LOCAL_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework-core

I'm having the service and I'm trying execute my code. I'm doing Join several tables from different DBs. In the place where I am using Entity Framework Core and doing .ToList() - it's throwing an exception (Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "LOCAL_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.).

PS. instead of "LOCAL_CI_AS" it could be any language: Arabic, Hebrew, Cyrilic. Sorry for confusing

I was checking DB Collation and all of them is the same (SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS), I suppose that issue happened due to some PC settings, but I have no idea from where it's coming. I found a way how to apply collation to special column, however it's not working for me because I'm doing 3 JOINs and all tables is very big. Thanks in advice

Comment: SQL Server has no `LOCAL_CI_AS` collation. Googling for `"LOCAL_CI_AS"` doesn't return anything at all - not unrelated results, no results at all. What did you actually try, using which EF Core version and which SQL Server version? What's the actual, complete exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()`? Not just `Exception.Message` but the entire string. This includes any inner exceptions and a call stack that could show which function calls resulted in the exception

Comment: `I'm doing Join several tables from different DBs` you shouldn't be using manual joins with any ORM, much less EF Core. It's the ORM's job to generate JOINs as needed from the relations between entities.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos instead of local it could be any language: Arabic, Hebrew, Cyrilic. Sorry for confusing

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think JOINs really depends on the situations, anyway it's not answering to my question

Comment: It *is* answering the question. You're using a tool that's meant to hide tables eliminate JOINs, to actually *JOIN tables*. Then you mention mixed collations in the same database. What else is going on? All these are serious design problems that lead to real bugs and performance problems. Those need to be fixed, not covered up. For example, you can cover up collation differences by adding a `COLLATE ...` clause in equalities or comparisons BUT that prevents the use of any indexes. JOINing tables with different collations will results in full table scans and M*N comparisons.

Comment: Why are there multiple collations in the same database, and why are you trying to join on them? That's the root of the problem. Do you use `varchar` or `nvarchar` columns? Using `varchar` makes the solution harder and adds the possibility of data mangling or loss. If you want to JOIN tables using indexes you need to use columns with the same collation in all tables. If you need to support multiple codepages, use `nvarchar` instead of `varchar` so you don't have to use the collation as a codepage, only to define the sort order.

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve localized messages? Or create a localized report? You can use different designs in different cases. For resources, the key/join column on all tables can be a resource identifier which can even be an integer.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos not sure that I got you. Let me clarify. First of all I checked collations of tables. They are the same. I checked the columns based on which I'm doing JOIN - they are same as well.

Comment: Post the code, tables and queries. Describe what you actually want to do, not how you think it can be done. Right now you're describing what you think the solution would look like. The trouble starts from even trying to join columns with different collations. Those columns need to have a single collation, especially if you have a lot of data. If the fields are `nvarchar` the change will be small. If not, it will be harder